# Weird bug when trying to change struct in function

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, pass-by-reference

I am creating a Ray Tracer following Peter Shirley's Ray Tracing In A Weekend Series to learn C and have encountered a weird bug in my program thats driving me crazy. In my `main` method in `main.c` I create a struct that holds information about all objects in the scene like so:

```
int main() {

    // Image

    const float aspect_ratio = 3.0 / 2.0;
    const int image_width = 400;
    const int image_height = (int) (image_width / aspect_ratio);
    const int samples_per_pixel = 40;
    const int max_depth = 50;

    // World
    hittable_list world; // Struct that holds all objects
```

I also have a function called `random_scene`(in main.c) that adds objects to this "world" as shown here:

```
void random_scene(hittable_list *world) {
    world->current_index = 0;
    

    material ground_material = (material) {LAMBERTIAN, .lam = col(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)};
    add_obj(world, (hittable) {.type = SPHERE, .s = (sphere){p3(0.0, -1000, 0), 1000, &ground_material}});
    
    material material1 = (material) {DIELECTRIC, .d = 1.5};
    add_obj(world, (hittable) {.type = SPHERE, .s = (sphere){p3(0, 1, 0), 1.0, &material1}});

    material material2 = (material) {LAMBERTIAN, .lam = col(0.4, 0.2, 0.1)};
    add_obj(world, (hittable) {.type = SPHERE, .s = (sphere){p3(-4, 1, 0), 1.0, &material2}});

    material material3 = (material) {METAL, .m = {(color){0.7, 0.6, 0.5}, 0.0}};
    add_obj(world, (hittable) {.type = SPHERE, .s = (sphere){p3(4, 1, 0), 1.0, &material3}});
}
```

The problem is when I call this function like this:

```
int main() {

    // Image

    const float aspect_ratio = 3.0 / 2.0;
    const int image_width = 400;
    const int image_height = (int) (image_width / aspect_ratio);
    const int samples_per_pixel = 40;
    const int max_depth = 50;

    // World
    hittable_list world;
    random_scene(&world);
```

and let the program run the image generated looks like this:
[image]

However if I add the objects like this:

```
int main() {

    // Image

    const float aspect_ratio = 3.0 / 2.0;
    const int image_width = 400;
    const int image_height = (int) (image_width / aspect_ratio);
    const int samples_per_pixel = 40;
    const int max_depth = 50;

    // World
    hittable_list world;
    world.current_index = 0;
    

    material ground_material = (material) {LAMBERTIAN, .lam = col(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)};
    add_obj(&world, (hittable) {.type = SPHERE, .s = (sphere){p3(0.0, -1000, 0), 1000, &ground_material}});
    
    material material1 = (material) {DIELECTRIC, .d = 1.5};
    add_obj(&world, (hittable) {.type = SPHERE, .s = (sphere){p3(0, 1, 0), 1.0, &material1}});

    material material2 = (material) {LAMBERTIAN, .lam = col(0.4, 0.2, 0.1)};
    add_obj(&world, (hittable) {.type = SPHERE, .s = (sphere){p3(-4, 1, 0), 1.0, &material2}});

    material material3 = (material) {METAL, .m = {(color){0.7, 0.6, 0.5}, 0.0}};
    add_obj(&world, (hittable) {.type = SPHERE, .s = (sphere){p3(4, 1, 0), 1.0, &material3}});
```

the image looks like this:
[image]

I dont really understand what is happening in the first way where I am passing in a pointer to the same object in that it is completely different then if I add the objects in main itself. I also tried changing the code so that `random_scene` returned the world both by itself and as a pointer or straight created the world in the function and returned it phowever nothing was working out. The full code is here if that is helpful to anyone: https://github.com/Lumijek/c-raytracer/tree/main.

Comment: `&ground_material` is the address of an object that is local the the function. That object not longer exists once `random_scene` is done, so you just stored a dangling pointer in your  `sphere` which was added to `world`

Comment: Would the best way to fix this be dynamically allocating the memory inside the function for the materials?

Comment: The way you have your code set up currently will most likely require dynamic memory allocation, yes. Another solution would be to have some sort of "material manager" that handles the material allocations (using e.g.: a fixed size array), but that requires more reworks